# Convert Row Based Data into XML

Tags: java, xml

I have a table with data in the following format:

[image]

I need to get into the following XML format:

```
<People>
     <Person>
          <FirstName>Mark</FirstName>
          <LastName>Smith</LastName>
          <PhoneNumbers>
               <PhoneNumber>
                    <Number>555-123-4567</Number>
                    <Type>Home</Type>
               </PhoneNumber>
               <PhoneNumber>
                    <Number>555-321-7654</Number>
                    <Type>Cell</Type>
               </PhoneNumber>
          <PhoneNumbers>
     <Person>
     <Person>
          <FirstName>Tim</FirstName>
          <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
          <PhoneNumbers>
               <PhoneNumber>
                    <Number>444-123-4567</Number>
                    <Type>Home</Type>
               </PhoneNumber>                   
          <PhoneNumbers>
     <Person>
     <Person>
          <FirstName>Larry</FirstName>
          <LastName>Walker</LastName>
          <PhoneNumbers>
               <PhoneNumber>
                    <Number>333-123-4567</Number>
                    <Type>Home</Type>
               </PhoneNumber>
               <PhoneNumber>
                    <Number>333-321-7654</Number>
                    <Type>Cell</Type>
               </PhoneNumber>
          <PhoneNumbers>
     <Person>
```

I am trying to discover the best practice way of doing this. Unfortunately, I have my hands tied with the process as I am forced read the rows of the table one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JAXB. Assuming that you know how to parse your table:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="People")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class People {
    @XmlElement(name = "Person")
    private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        persons.add(person);
    } 
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Person {
    String FirstName;
    List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumber;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class PhoneNumber {
    String Number;
    String Type;
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        PhoneNumber phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
        phoneNumber.Number = "555-555-555";
        phoneNumber.Type = "Home";

        Person person = new Person();
        person.FirstName = "Peter";
        person.PhoneNumber = Arrays.asList(phoneNumber, phoneNumber);

        People people = new People();
        people.addPerson(person);
        people.addPerson(person);

        StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
        JAXB.marshal(people, s);

        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Note that the code needs reactoring to look better